# Chrome Warning of Multiple Files Download, despite only being one file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I never had the issue before, but whenever I try to download a file programmatically, chrome blocks the attempt and warns me, that the page wanted to download multiple files... which they are not.

[image]

I receive a JSON with a few informations, but one of the fields is called `documentContentB64`and has a single base64 encoded pdf-file. The code below (kept a bit simpler for brevity) at the end, if I allow Chrome to download multiple files, simply gives me one PDF as expected.

```
  downloadInvoicePdfData() {
    this.httpClient.get('<url>',
      { observe: 'response' }).subscribe((invoiceFile: any) => {
        this.downloadPdf(invoiceFile.body.documentContentB64);
      });
  }

  private downloadPdf(base64File: string) {
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    const file = base64File;
    downloadLink.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + file;
    downloadLink.download = `invoice.pdf`;
    downloadLink.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true, view: window }));

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadLink.href);
    downloadLink.remove();
  }
```

Comment: What does your Chrome Dev Tools tell you? Specifically the Network tab.

Comment: @mxmissile Nothing aside what I added as an image in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have no legit explanation for this. I went back to an "older" solution of mine, which works with BLOBs and... it simply works. Chrome doesn't complain when you do the nigh-same steps for setting up a programmatic download when provided with an ObjectUrl of a blob. I need to research this.

```
async downloadPdf(base64File: string) {
    this.fileLink = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64File;

    const base64Response = await fetch(this.fileLink);
    const blob = await base64Response.blob();

    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.download = 'invoice.pdf';
    downloadLink.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true, view: window }));
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadLink.href);
    downloadLink.remove();
  }
```